# Ionic 2: publish multiple events on Modal dismiss sometimes doesn't work

Tags: events, angular, promise, ionic2

I've got a modal window that when you click 'Add', it does its thing, dismisses, and then when the promise is resolved, publishes some events that tell relevant components to update:

```
this._viewControl.dismiss().then(() => 
    this._events.publish('update_myJobsPage', null);
    this._events.publish('update_assessmentsPage', null);
    this._events.publish('update_buildingPage', null);        
});
```

Problem is, sometimes it works and they update their views, sometimes not.  The modal always dismisses and the events fire though.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion, could you not just have one event `update_pages` and have each page handle the same event?

Comment: I could do, but I prefer to have each page subscribe to its own event so I can more granularly control what pages update and when.

Comment: Ok. I think what LeRoy suggests with using `onDismiss()` is at least the right way to trigger the events, whether that will fix your issue or not though I don't know

Answer (score 2):

> Problem is, sometimes it works and they update their views, sometimes
>   not.

As you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174997/angular-2-ionic-2-detect-if-an-object-was-modified#answer-38180523), Application state change is caused by three things:

1) Events - User events like click, change, input, submit, …

2) XMLHttpRequests - E.g. when fetching data from a remote service Timers -

3) setTimeout(),setInterval(), because JavaScript

**It turns out that these are the only cases when Angular is actually interested in updating the view.**

So if you want to update other things *outside Angular way*, you will have to let Angular know that something has changed and needs to we aware of updating things. You can do this by first importing `ngZone` like this:

`import { ..., NgZone } from '@angular/core';`

Declaring it in your `constructor` like this:

```
constructor(..., private ngZone: NgZone ) { //... }
```

And then surrounding your code inside a *zone*

```
this._viewControl.dismiss().then(() => 

  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // Execute here what you want and Angular will update the view for you.
    // ...    
    this._events.publish('update_myJobsPage', null);
    this._events.publish('update_assessmentsPage', null);
    this._events.publish('update_buildingPage', null);

  });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `onDismiss` ?

```
 this._viewControl.onDismiss(() => {
    this._events.publish('update_myJobsPage', null);
    this._events.publish('update_assessmentsPage', null);
    this._events.publish('update_buildingPage', null); 
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the right solution.  Using dismiss().then(...) is the stated way to do it from the Ionic 2 docs I've found, and it works everywhere else in my app!

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out, if I empty out my collection when I'm refreshing, so..

e.g

```
updatePage() {
    this.myCollection = [];
    this.someService.getItems().then(items => {
        this.myCollection = items;
    });
}
```

then the page always shows the update.  So I'm going to put this one down to a timing/change detection bug in Angular 2 and move on!

Comment: Please read my answer. The page shows the update because an application state change is caused by XMLHttpRequests (when calling the `someService` service). But you could improve that by using _NgZone_.

Comment: Actually it's not, because my service is fetching from local storage database, not an external http service.

Comment: Oh I see... maybe the `then()` has something to do? Will do a few tests later today. Thanks @Dave for letting me know that by the way.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your in depth explanation. The key to my issue I think is that sometimes it worked, sometimes not, which means it's not an angular 2 change detection issue, rather a timing issue with promises, transitions (modal pages dismissing animation) and the Ionic 2 framework.

Comment: turns out this didn't fully work.  Going with NgZone. Thanks.