# Model update not reflected in UI only on second NavController page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a bizarre problem that when I change a value in the model, it does not update the view. My demo is a simple page which displays a timer whose value is updated in the model which I want reflected in the UI:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
     template: '<ion-content>Ticks (every second) : {{ticks}}</ion-content>',
})
export class ProgramOverviewPage {
  ticks = 0;
  ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(0, 1000);
    timer.subscribe(t => { this.ticks = t; console.log(t);});
  }
}
```

If I set this page as my root page, it works fine. However, if I set a different page as my root page, and then immediately navigate to the timer page:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.nav.push(ProgramOverviewPage, {
  });
}
```

then the page renders, but the tick value does not update the UI. I can't think of anything other than that the NavController is messing with the ChangeDetector, but I don't know why that would be. Anything I can add to debug this is much appreciated.

```
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.10"
```

Comment: Did you try telling the changedetectorref to detect changes?

Comment: What about doing the `this.ticks = t` inside `this.ngZone.run(() => {}` like you can see [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174997/angular-2-ionic-2-detect-if-an-object-was-modified/38180523#38180523)

Comment: @misha130 Yes I tried that, no change. Also, this should only be needed if the change detector is set to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, which it is not.

Comment: @sebaferreras Yes that solved it! If you'd like to write that up as an answer (especially if you know why this is necessary when it doesn't seem like it should be), I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll write my own answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Fun Fact: I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GwVjR731iu1eWES1LkfR?p=preview) by creating a `HomePage` that only redirects to the `Page1` (the one with the timer) but the view gets updated properly. So... I'm kind of confused... would you mind taking a look to that plunker to see which are the differences with your code and why this works when your code doesnt?

Comment: @sebaferreras I've reproduced the problem at http://plnkr.co/edit/tcNGEMdjbQ42Fw9p5jty by setting ChangeDetection to OnPush. I had previously thought it was Default strategy, but I just installed Augurgy and I see that Ionic 2 is automatically setting CD to OnPush for every Content component. It even sets this for the first page, so I don't know why the update seems to work in my example, but this knowledge now tells me why updates don't get pushed to the UI in my Ionic application.

Comment: @misha130 I just realized that I was calling the wrong method on the CD. When I invoke cd.detectChanges(), then the UI updates correctly. I'm going to use this instead of ngZone because from what I read, fewer components are rechecked.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you've found the _why_ (and the better way to solve it) And like you say, I agree with you that **your way is more efficient than using ngZone**. Would you please add that to the answer? So other users can find that easily :)

Comment: @sebaferreras Unless you want to write the answer, I can do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Shawn Lauzon, feel free to add the answer because there's something I still don't undertand about this issue. We have two plunkers, [one works](http://plnkr.co/edit/GwVjR731iu1eWES1LkfR?p=preview) and the [other one doesn't](http://plnkr.co/edit/tcNGEMdjbQ42Fw9p5jty?p=preview) and the only difference between them is that `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. So that tells me that Ionic2 by default uses the **Default strategy** which is _to traverse all the components of the tree even if they do not seem to have been modified_ and that's why the first plunker works.

Comment: @sebaferreras I'm guessing there's a lot of scaffolding that Ionic 2 includes that's not part of the plunker. I do know that [Augury](https://augury.angular.io/) shows the Change Detection from every single Content object is OnPush. This might be some configuration option, but I didn't intentionally set it, and definitely didn't with the `changeDetection` option like in plunker #2.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 2 seems to be automatically setting Change Detection to OnPush for each of the Content objects (generated from `<ion-content>` I believe). This can be verified by using [Augury](https://augury.angular.io/) and clicking on the Content object.

Because of this, it's necessary to explicitly tell the change detection system whenever you make any change which should be pushed to the UI using the `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` method. See the [thoughtram blog](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) for details.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-content>Ticks (every second) : {{ticks}}</ion-content>',
})
export class ProgramOverviewPage {
  ticks = 0;
  ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(0, 1000);
    timer.subscribe(t => { 
      this.ticks = t; 
      console.log(t);
      this.cd.detectChanges(); // Invoke the change detector
    });
  }
}
```