# Ionic 2 increment decrement quantity for each product

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So i wanted to input quantity for each product, but everytime I click the increment button, the other products is also incremented, How do I increment the quantity of the product without affecting the other ? Also, I want to calculate the amount due by multiplying its quantity with the price, how should I do this ?[image]

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are using a common/single varable 'currentNumber' to all products. Use seperate variable 'currentNumber' for each product like 'product.PCode'

Comment: <b>{{product.PPrice * currentNumber}}<\b>

Comment: The next time please add the actual code instead of an image of it, so it's easier to include it in the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

In your component code, first initialize a `quantity` property for each `product` in the `productlist`

```
// After getting the list of products...
this.productlist.foreach(product => { product.quantity = 0; });
// ...
```

Also update the `decrement` and `increment` functions to receive the `product` that should be modified:

```
increment(product: any) {
  product.quantity++;
}

decrement(product: any) {
  if(product.quantity > 0) {
    product.quantity--;
  }
}
```

Now in the view, you can use the new `quantity` property to show the quantity multiplied by the price. Also notice that now we sent the `product` to the `increment` and `decrement` functions:

```
<ion-icon ... (click)="decrement(product)"></ion-icon>
{{ product.quantity * product.PPrice }}
<ion-icon ... (click)="increment(product)"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: Why is it that the value of product.quantity is NaN ? how should i fix it ?

Comment: Have you added this line of code in the component code, as soon as you get the list of products? `this.productlist.foreach(product => { product.quantity = 0; });`

Comment: @sebaferreras I have just one component to calculate the quantity but when I increment and decrement the {{quantity}} it doesn't update in the view unless I do some randon clicks in the UI any guesses?

Comment: Could you please take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174997/angular-2-ionic-2-detect-if-an-object-was-modified/38180523#38180523)** to see if `NgZone` helps Angular detecting that the view needs to be updated? @FernandoZamperin

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras I saw an article explaining about NgZone and yes you're right that worked thanks a lot!!

Comment: So glad to hear that @FernandoZamperin :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let product of cart; let index=index">

<strong> ₹ {{ item_qty *  product.price  }}</strong>

<ion-card>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-cart',
templateUrl: 'cart.html',
})
export class CartPage implements OnInit {

 item_qty:any;

constructor()
{this.item_qty=1;}

// increment item 
inc(){
this.item_qty += 1;
console.log(this.item_qty + 1);
}

//decrements item

dec(){
if(this.item_qty-1 < 1){
  this.item_qty = 1;
  console.log('item_1->' + this.item_qty)
}
else{
  this.item_qty -= 1;
  console.log('item_2->' + this.item_qty);
}
}

}
```