# View not refreshing after an attributte is modified on Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, promise, es6-promise

I don't know why, but in a moment i started to have a weird problem with ionic 2 (or angular in it's defect).

When I update an attributte value with a promise response, the value is being updated properly but the view is not refreshing. For example retrieving local storage data or mock data with promises. 
If I do a console.log I can see i'm getting the new value, but the view is not updating. I use `ChangeDetectorRef` from `angular/core` but I call `detectChanges()` method in all the promise's responses and it's an ugly workaround.

For example this code:

```
public getReminders(): void {
    this.reminderProvider.getAllReminders().then((reminders) => {
        this.reminders = reminders;

        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    })
    .catch(() => {
        this.setDefaultReminder();
    });
}

public setDefaultReminder(): void {
    this.reminderProvider.defaultReminder().then(defaultReminder => {
        this.reminders.push(defaultReminder);

        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I need to use `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` to force a "view refresh" but this should not be necesary.

Comment: Please take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174997/angular-2-ionic-2-detect-if-an-object-was-modified/38180523#38180523)**, it may help :)

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful and well explained. It served me! If you want to make an answer, do it and I'll point to you as a valid answer :)

Comment: So glad to hear that it helped! I've marked your question as a duplicate, so all SO users coming to this question can read that answer as well. _Saludos che!_ :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, capo! ;) Saludos!